# Can't import file inside inline babel ReactJS unpkg

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys im using React and React-DOM unpkg to add react to my webpage. i also use babel unpkg to enable jsx. but i have problem when im importing   another file. here is the file code

```
class Trial extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Trial;
```

then i import it inside my html with this code

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const Trial = require('./App')

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar">
                <Trial />

                ......

            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

but it keep resulting error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at <anonymous>:38:14
at n (babel.min.js:12)
at r (babel.min.js:12)
at o (babel.min.js:12)
at u (babel.min.js:12)
at E (babel.min.js:1)
```

anyone knows what happen?

Comment: Babel does transpile JSX, but it does not make `require()` work in the browser. Are you able to use [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) instead? That'd be my preferred route

Comment: @kingdaro CRA would be great, but i need to combine the app with Laravel one. The page im working on only used for searching feature, the rest is using Laravel. so i using unpkg. any workaround you can provide?

Comment: You can still use CRA and have your Laravel app reference the files built by CRA, in the `build` folder. If you want more flexibility here, you could roll your own custom webpack build, and have your app reference the output JS file. Or, use a simple tool like parcel. Any sort of module bundling process, really. The alternative is putting everything in global scope, but that would be a maintainability nightmare

Comment: @kingdaro thx, i'll try ur suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to `import` / `require` at runtime, either use the [`import`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement – which is nowadays widely supported in evergreen browsers –, or use a dynamic module loader library such as [SystemJS](http://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) (the latter is ancient though).

---

Also, doing the *JSX transform* at runtime is **not** recommended in production.

Comment: The error can't be the same (`require is not defined`) if you're using an `import` statement.. What exactly did you try?

Comment: same error mate. i use export defaut App in App.js and use import App from './App' in index.html

Comment: Correct syntax is `import App from './App.js'` but it has to be in a `<script type='module'>` element, which is not possible in your case because you have to use the `text/babel` type.

Comment: yeah, i try to import it by script type/babel and got error

Comment: Solution is to either **a)** not use JSX **b)** use SystemJS or **c)** just use a module bundler like `webpack` (what create-react-app uses) or `rollup`